# learnin the english. ing grammar and simple present

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

which sentence is correct?

1-meditation really relax you.
2-meditation really relaxing you.

we should use present simple or present continuous?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If all you give us is two short sentences or phrases, and the only difference between them is the tense (in this case, present simple vs. present continuous), then "Which one is correct?" is pretty much a meaningless question.**

**Either one can be correct, depending on whether or not the situation calls for one tense or the other.**

For example, let's say you open a meditation room, and you are trying to tout its benefits in your colorful new brochures. In this case, the simple present would be the way to go:

> Meditation really helps you.

But let's say Jane and Jill go to the meditation room together, and Jane is watching the tension leave Jill's face. In this case, Jane is talking about what is happening in the moment, rather than some always-true meditation benefit. In this case, Jane might say something like:

> Wow! You look way more relaxed than you did thirty minutes ago. This meditation is really helping you.